# struggling to understand how "collapsed margin" works for "parent and first/last child"

Tags: css, web, margin

I'm currently learning about [collapsed margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) on MDN. Collapsed margin for adjacent siblings are pretty easy to understand. However, I'm struggling to understand how collapsed margin works for "parent and first/last child", especially the last sentence highlighted in blue.

How could a collapsed margins ends up outside the parent? I can't seem to picture it in my head.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? The `50px` margin on `.outer` and `100px` margin on `.inner` have collapsed to a single `100px` margin from `.inner`, and `.inner`'s margin is outside of the parent, rather than inside like you would expect.

```css
.outer {
  background: #eee;
  height: 100px;
}
.inner {
  background: red;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting example for you. The first parent does not have a border set. It automatically assumes that you do not want to use the child margin, yet it does stand of from the top.
The second example does have a border set. Now the browser assumes you explicitly want to make use of the native margin of the h1 tag and the parent adapts to show this.

```css
.parent1 {
  background-color: #669;
}
.parent2 {
  background-color: #969;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">

  <h1>hello World</h1>

</div>

<div class="parent2">

  <h1>hello World</h1>

</div>
```